# drupal_static_reset causing errors

Tags: 7, theming

I have developed a custom template for a node where I wanted to essentially show the node in a blank white page.  I created a file called node--results.tpl.php and page--node--results.tpl.php that removed just about everything except a few divs.  In my module, I have function called `results_view_preprocess_node` that adds the custom javascripts and css files I needed and removed.

```
function results_view_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

  if ($variables['view_mode'] == 'full') {
    $node = &$variables['node'];
    if ($node->type == 'results') {
      //remove all other CSS files
      drupal_static_reset('drupal_add_css');

      $path = drupal_get_path('module','results_view');
      drupal_add_css($path . '/css/styles.css');
      drupal_add_css('sites/all/libraries/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css');
      drupal_add_js('/sites/all/libraries/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js');

      $id = $variables['nid'];
      drupal_add_js(
        'meetdir="/files/results/' . $id .'";',
        array(
          'type' => 'inline',
          'scope' => 'header',
          'weight' => 5,
          'group' => JS_LIBRARY,
        )
      );

      drupal_add_js(
        array(
          'results_view' => array(
            'path' => drupal_get_path('module','results_view'),
          ),
        ),
        'setting'
       );
      drupal_add_js(
        $path . '/js/advancedResults.js',
        array(
         'type' => 'file',
         'scope' => 'header',
         'group' => JS_LIBRARY,
        )
      );
      drupal_add_js(
        $path . '/js/filter.js',
        array(
          'type' => 'file',
          'scope' => 'header',
          'group' => JS_LIBRARY,
        )
      );

      //drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($variables,true) . '</pre>','warning');
    }

  }
}
```

I've noticed that when I load a node of this type, I get a large number of warnings and have narrowed it down to `drupal_static_reset('drupal_add_css');`.  **When I comment this line out, I don't get the warnings**, but then I don't get a clean page.

```
Notice: Undefined index: group in drupal_sort_css_js() (line 3129 of /mysites/html/development/drupal/includes/common.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: group in drupal_sort_css_js() (line 3129 of /mysites/html/development/drupal/includes/common.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: group in drupal_sort_css_js() (line 3132 of /mysites/html/development/drupal/includes/common.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: every_page in drupal_sort_css_js() (line 3139 of /mysites/html/development/drupal/includes/common.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: every_page in drupal_sort_css_js() (line 3142 of /mysites/html/development/drupal/includes/common.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: weight in drupal_sort_css_js() (line 3146 of /mysites/html/development/drupal/includes/common.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: weight in drupal_sort_css_js() (line 3149 of /mysites/html/development/drupal/includes/common.inc).
Warning: uasort(): Array was modified by the user comparison function in drupal_get_css() (line 3063 of /mysites/html/development/drupal/includes/common.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: type in drupal_get_css() (line 3080 of /mysites/html/development/drupal/includes/common.inc).
Warning: ksort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in drupal_group_css() (line 3206 of /mysites/html/development/drupal/includes/common.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: type in drupal_group_css() (line 3218 of /mysites/html/development/drupal/includes/common.inc).
Notice: Undefined variable: group_keys in drupal_group_css() (line 3238 of /mysites/html/development/drupal/includes/common.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: type in drupal_aggregate_css() (line 3279 of /mysites/html/development/drupal/includes/common.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: type in drupal_pre_render_styles() (line 3399 of /mysites/html/development/drupal/includes/common.inc).
```

As far as I have been able to tell, this is the technique you're supposed to use to create a separate template for a node, but obviously, I'm missing something.  What do I need to do to fix this?

**EDIT**
Looking at the rendered HTML, both CSS files I add using `drupal_add_css` are linked like this:

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">
   @import url("http://www.oregonswimming.org/sites/all/modules/results_view/css/styles.css?ngdwh6");
   @import url("http://www.example.com/sites/all/libraries/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css?ngdwh6");
   @import url("http://www.example.com/modules/shortcut/shortcut.css?ngdwh6");
   @import url("http://www.example.com/modules/toolbar/toolbar.css?ngdwh6");
 </style>
```

Comment: `drupal_add_css()` does add those array indexes, when they are not present. The problem is not the code you are showing.

Comment: jQuery Update module provides jQuery UI up to version 1.10.2. Is there something specific you need in 1.10.4 ? or is it the custom UI theme ?

Comment: That's just the latest version I have. The jQuery version shouldn't have anything to do with the PHP errors.

Comment: Can you try making all the drupal_add_css absolute, or set 'external' after them:
drupal_add_css(LOCATION,'external');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing `drupal_static_reset('drupal_add_css');` from my code and overriding all the drupal css styles in my own CSS file.  It's a pain but the only way I can find to get rid of all the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if group, page, weight etc are missing or undefined, try this :

```
$file = drupal_get_path('module','results_view') . '/css/styles.css';
drupal_add_css($file, array(
    'type' => 'file',
    'group' => CSS_DEFAULT,
    'every_page' => TRUE,
    'weight' => 0),
    );
```

Maybe following a `drupal_static_reset('drupal_add_css');` calls to `drupal_add_css` need these attributes. Perhaps the functions defaults get reset as well.

Comment: `drupal_add_css()` initializes those array indexes already, as long as the first argument is not `NULL`: `if (isset($data)) { }`.

Comment: I presumed so, looking at the docs. but wondered if it worked for the OP ? if it does (or even if it doesn't) it looks like something else is causing the problem.

Comment: Your suggestion was promising, but didn't work.

Comment: @Robbert Clearly, it is something else causing the problem, probably a module. Possibly there is one that doesn't call `drupal_add_css()`.

Comment: I'm using drupal_static_reset to remove all drupal css files. That's what I read was the technique to accomplish this. The problem goes away when I comment out that line but then I have styles from other css files I don't want on this node page. It seems to me this is a bug in common.inc not checking if the array key exists before doing its thing.